# Find all positive integers $n$,$m$ with $n! = \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers.
Find all solutions of the equation
$n! = \frac{m(m-1)}{2}$.

I found the following solutions: $(1,2)$, $(3,4)$, $(5,16)$, 
and tried to find more solutions with a computer, 
but there is no other solution with $n$ smaller than $1000$.

Comment: You may want to look at [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/triangular-factorials).

Comment: Yes, it's the same question, but it seems, that it is still open.