# Integer Equation $m ! = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: number-theory

As reported by Christopher M. Tomaszewski in the [A000217 OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A000217) ,

$m, n , s > 0$ , $m ! = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = s$

has only a solution $s \in \{ 1 , 6 , 120 \}$ .

This may be quickly checked by comparing the 2 sequences. A simulation lets think that it is exact.

How to prove it analytically ( and rigorously ) ?

Edit : then it is an official conjecture ! It seems that it is not out of reach for MSE ... I'll work on it too.

Comment: Doesn't "*Conjecturally*, 1, 6, 120 are the only numbers that are both triangular and factorial. - Christopher M. Tomaszewski (cmt1288(AT)comcast.net), Mar 30 2005" mean that the thing you ask is an open conjecture formulated by Tomaszewski in 2005 ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli OK !! the word conjecture is not in the Sloane page. Do you have an idea on how to start before more difficulties ? TY ( or I translated badly "Conjecturally" which means other thing in french )

Comment: @danielMclaury : Thank you for the title

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is one of many open problems relating factorials and values of polynomials, see Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory for similar, but not identical, problems.

Comment: Apparently, [someone already asked this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/triangular-factorials), and there was a discussion in various comments about that "conjecturally".

Comment: It seems that for sufficiently large $m$ to verify that there is no solutions we can use asymptotic for prime numbers and show that square root of Stirling approximation of factorial is lower than closest prime number below or equal given $m$, can't we?

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi: it seems a good starting point ! I feel we ( or you :) ) will find something. I was working on holes, trying to find the holes in the second member ( while the left one hasn't )

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi How could the square root of $m!$ be lower than $m$ for large $m$? Or maybe I didn't understand you comment?

Comment: @WillJagy better fit for MO then ?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: you are right, I mismathed orders of growth when thought of it

Comment: @WillJagy : what does mean a made up question ? how are the made down ones ?

Comment: " Vladimir Reshetnikov: From e-mail communication with Christopher M. Tomaszewski I learnt that he found that his purported proof of 1-6-120 conjecture was incorrect. But he claimed that there is no counterexample below 10^77337, so it still remains an interesting conjecture. Consequently "Conjecturally" was added on Jan 16 2012"